# How to implement reCaptcha into my signup form?

Tags: php, forms, validation, registration, recaptcha

I am kinda new to php and i am trying to figure out how to make recaptcha work on my site.

Here is an excerpt from my "signup.php" and i have corresponding signup.html which acts like a template... The head part of it looks like below...

```
<?php
require_once('includes/config.php');
require_once('includes/functions/func.global.php');
require_once('includes/classes/class.template_engine.php');
require_once('includes/lang/lang_'.$config['lang'].'.php');
// Connect to database
db_connect($config);
// Start Session
session_start();
```

The security part of the code is...

```
if($config['security'])
 {
  $_POST['security_code'] = trim($_POST['security_code']);

  if(strtoupper($_POST['security_code']) != strtoupper($_SESSION['seccode']))
  {
   $security_error = $lang['INVALIDSECWORD'];
   $errors++;
  }
 }

 if($errors == 0)
 {
  $rem = md5(mt_rand(0,56)*time());

  if($config['validation'] == '1')
  {
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO `".$config['db']['pre']."users` ( `user_id` , `username` , `password` , `email` , `remember` , `status` ) VALUES ('', '".validate_input($_POST['username'])."', '".validate_input(md5($_POST['password']))."', '".validate_input($_POST['email'])."', '".validate_input($rem)."', '0');");

   $user_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

At the very end...it loads the signup template...

```
// Load signup template
$page = new HtmlTemplate ('templates/' . $config['tpl_name'] . '/signup.html');
$page->SetParameter ('OVERALL_HEADER', create_header($config,$lang,$cats,$lang['SIGNUP']));
$page->SetParameter ('OVERALL_FOOTER', create_footer($config,$lang));
$page->SetLoop ('CATS', $cats);
if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
 $page->SetParameter ('USERNAME_FIELD', $_POST['username']);
 $page->SetParameter ('EMAIL_FIELD', $_POST['email']);

 $page->SetParameter ('USERNAME_ERROR', $username_error);
 $page->SetParameter ('PASSWORD_ERROR', $password_error);
 $page->SetParameter ('EMAIL_ERROR', $email_error);
 $page->SetParameter ('AGREE_ERROR', $agree_error);
 $page->SetParameter ('SECURITY_ERROR', $security_error);
}
else
{
 $page->SetParameter ('USERNAME_FIELD', '');
 $page->SetParameter ('EMAIL_FIELD', '');

 $page->SetParameter ('USERNAME_ERROR', '');
 $page->SetParameter ('PASSWORD_ERROR', '');
 $page->SetParameter ('EMAIL_ERROR', '');
 $page->SetParameter ('AGREE_ERROR', '');
 $page->SetParameter ('SECURITY_ERROR', '');
}
if(isset($_SESSION['duser']['id']))
{
 $page->SetParameter ('LOGGEDIN', 1);
}
else
{
 $page->SetParameter ('LOGGEDIN', 0);
}
$page->SetParameter ('SECURITY_CODE',$config['security']);
$page->SetParameter ('SITE_TITLE',$config['site_title']);
$page->CreatePageEcho($lang,$config);
```

Now i am wondering where i need to insert the code for recaptcha...i have signed up and i got to the part where i user require function to include recaptcha lib but after that, i am not sure what code i need to insert in which part to replace usual generation of random image with recaptcha...

Any directions, tips or solutions would really be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking at the documentation? http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/php.html

Comment: More specifically, recaptcha_get_html($publickey);

Comment: i tried looking at the documentation but i find it hard to replace it with the exisiting system of security code generation...i have another file named "seccode.php" that generates an image and passes to this file with  the code above...I need to replace this system with recaptcha...